# Select free times in schedule sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this :

```
    day      start        end
2013-01-02  08:00:00    12:00:00
2013-01-02  16:00:00    18:00:00
2013-01-02  23:00:00    03:00:00
2013-01-03  08:00:00    12:00:00
2013-01-03  16:00:00    18:00:00
2013-01-03  23:00:00    03:00:00
```

What i want to do is a select to the table thath results in this :

```
     day      start        end
2013-01-02  12:00:00    16:00:00
2013-01-02  18:00:00    23:00:00
```

Displaying the free times i have on that schedule , i have been trying for hours cant realyze how to do it please help

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Congrats . . . I think you are the 50th tag on sql-server-2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only seem to want in-between times.  So you can use `lead()`:

```
select day, end, nextstart
from (select t.*, lead(start) over (partition by day order by start) as nextstart
      from table t
     ) t
where end <> nextstart;
```

(Note:  I haven't escaped the reserved words for clarity.  You shouldn't really name columns things like `end` and `day` which are reserved words.)

This is a bit more challenging if you want 0:00-8:00 for instance.

Comment: thath worked , tho i cant see the free time from 03:00 - 8:00 free time can you help me?

Comment: @user3648078, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking check button if it helped.